# Using.filter() method without a function

Tags: javascript

I saw this solution on codewars

```
    "strict mode";
let testarr = [true,true,false,true,true];

function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) {
  return arrayOfSheeps.filter(Boolean).length;
}

console.log(countSheeps(testarr))
```

How does this work? I thought that for the filter method to work a function must be passed into it rather than a data type or value. I tried this with an array of numbers and replaced the word "boolean" with "number" and also actual numbers eg 3. Yet this didnt work - So why does it work with boolean here?

Comment: [`Boolean` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is not a data type. try `typeof Boolean`

Comment: [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) is a function.

Comment: Oh okay so true and false are of data type boolean?

Answer (score 2):

It utilizes the [`Boolean` builtin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), which can be used as a function.

```
Boolean(1); // => true
Boolean(0); // => false
```

Comment: More accurately, "which *is* a function".

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is a function, and .filter method takes function.

So it is same as like following code;

```js
 "strict mode";
let testarr = [true,true,false,true,true];

function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) {
  return arrayOfSheeps.filter((sheep) => Boolean(sheep)).length;
}

console.log(countSheeps(testarr))
```